# Calling a method with only the dot Separator in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, methods

I am having trouble understanding the following syntax in a function of the alamofire library.

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://someWebsite.com/api/", parameters: ["key":"2121"])
         .responseJSON { response in
                   if let JSON = response.result.value {
                        print("JSON: \(JSON)")
                    }
            }
```

Why doesn't the `responseJSON` method have a prefix? Moreover, why does this method have a completion handler in its body , shouldn't it be the method's parameter? i.e.

```
    .responesJSON( response in ... )
```

OR

```
    .responseJSON(){respones in ....}
```

Answer (score 3):

> Why doesn't the responseJSON method have a prefix?

If you look from the compiler point of view, responseJSON has a prefix: responseJSON is a method which gets called on the result of request method.
It seems like it doesn't have a prefix because of the carriage return and indentation, but you can put .responseJSON function right after the closing parenthesis of request method.

This is a design choice made by developers of Alamofire: request function returns the same object on which it was called, so you can call another function on the same object without having to repeat the Alamofire prefix. 
This is common on this types of scenario, where you need to call several functions on the same object to setup things.

> why does this method have a completion handler in its body , shouldn't it be the method's parameter?

In Swift, if the only parameter of a method or function is a closure (eg. a completion handler) you can make an abbreviation and write

```
.responseJSON { response in ... }
```

instead of

```
.responseJSON ({response in ...})
```

or

```
.responseJSON(){ response in ...})
```